# Как обновлять значение переменной? JS JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Я решил делать очень простенькую игрушку. По стандарту, персонажу задаётся вопрос, 3 варианта ответа, после выбора добавляется опыт, уменьшаются жизни. Хочу научиться делать всё правильно и клиент-серверно с Ajax, JSON и всеми вытекающими. Или может у меня вообще не правильная логика приложения...

Допустим есть переменная `lives`. Например, `lives = 4`. Дальше, при неком событии, `lives` соответственно добавляется или уменьшается и это отображается в строке состояния. Не по таймеру, т.к. я всегда знаю, когда нужно обновлять данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как раз добавлять и показывать это в "интерфейсе" пользователя не понятно как. Где размещать, хранить **правильно** эти данные?

Ок, я беру Ajax'ом отправляю данные на сервер, но... уже здесь не ясно где хранить переменную? В php или в JS? Потом возвращать как и куда... Совсем запутался. Может есть смысл на node.js сервер замутить, но туда я пока не лез. Мне в целом бы логику понять происходящего.

Comment: Вообще, хранение данных осуществляется не в php или js, а в базе данных

Comment: Вот это интереснее. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Кол-во жизней / опыта и пр. «достижения» будем называть *состоянием* (state) игрока. Его можно хранить только в браузере (local storage), можно хранить у вас на сервере, или, скажем, во ВКонтакте, если это игра для ВК.

- Авторизуется ли пользователь в вашей игре?
- Есть ли вычисления, которые делаются на сервере, связи с другими игроками?

Если вы только начинаете разработку игры и это первые шаги, начните с простого: сделайте игру только-в-браузере. Сохранять данные можно в local storage – чтобы продолжить в другой раз с того места, где остновился.

Потом уже докрутите сохранение данных ещё и на сервер, рекорды и т.п.